# Saving binary file in Matlab in a loop?

Tags: matlab, file, file-io

Consider a matrix `A` in Matlab of dimension `mxn` and suppose I want to save it as a binary file `test.dat` using

```
File_id = fopen('test.dat', 'w');
fwrite(File_id, A, 'float32');
fclose(File_id);
```

Now suppose that A is created within a loop for `h=1:100`: how can I assign to the binary files the names `test1.dat, test2.dat,...,test100.dat`? In other words this is what I want to do and my question is related to step 2):

```
%for h=1:H
    %1)do something that creates A
    %2) Save A using
    %File_id = fopen('test'h'.dat', 'w'); %clearly wrong
    %fwrite(File_id, A, 'float32'); 
    %fclose(File_id);
%end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you posted, the line:

```
%File_id = fopen('test'h'.dat', 'w'); %clearly wrong
```

should read:

```
File_id = fopen(strcat('test',num2str(h),'.dat'),'w');
```

and that should do the trick nicely.

Comment: Instead of `strcat('test',num2str(h),'.dat')` you could also use `['test' num2str(h) '.dat']`

Comment: Or `sprintf('test%02u.dat', h)`. The advantage there is that by specifying `%02u`, where 2 is a field width and the leading zero pads the field unused part of the field with zeros, the files will be rationally sorted on your drive, i.e. test2.dat lists right before test20.dat, but test02.dat lists in its proper order.

Comment: You could also do  `['test' num2str(h,'%02d') '.dat']` since num2str takes an optional formatSpec input ...  That is one thing I kind of like about Matlab, lots and lots of ways to go about doing something.